# Predefined Skillset in azure search : How it internally work?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search

There are predefine skillset in azure which work with indexer, while indexer inject data from datasource to index how it work with predefined skillset like: how it get person name, location name etc

Answer (score 0):

The output will be documents in your index. All you have to do is query your index than extracting the information you want.

More info about Cognitive Search:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-intro

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-working-with-skillsets